# How to identify types with the serialization attribute?

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to define a method parameter that should ideally only accept object arguments that have been decorated with the `Serializable` attribute. The method task is to persist the object argument into a XML document.

I understand I can eventually check for `SerializationException`, but i'd rather be able to neatly define this as a part of the method contract. So, is there any way I can isolate types that have been decorated with this attribute?

Comment: This question was answered by aligray (and Reddog for that matter), but I can't seem to go back and accept an answer since I unknowingly asked it in anonymous mode. My apologies for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use the `IsSerializable` property of the `Type` class:

```
public void Serialize(object obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType().IsSerializable)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: Serializable decorated objects don't automatically implement ISerializable. Also, I don't question my ability to check for the type validity in the body of the function. What I would like to know is if I can make a contract with the caller in which only objects with the serializable attribute can be passed as an argument.

Comment: The `IsSerializable` property returns true for classes decorated with `[Serializable]`, but *not* for classes which implement `ISerializable`.

Comment: I believe the only way to do this is to make your classes implement `ISerializable`, as suggested @Frank Boyne.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetCustomAttributes` function on the type of the object.

```
    public void Serialize(object itemToSerialize)
    {
        var hasAttribute = itemToSerialize.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true).Any();

        // Do stuff.
    }
```

However, don't forget that normal serialization supports `ISerializable` too. So therefore, the `IsSerializable` property on the type is probably more appropriate.

**Edit** I think you are after a manner to have the compiler enforce the parameter have the attribute. There is no way to do this. You would have to use a runtime check as above and throw an exception.

Generics would typically be your friend for this type of task, and in this case, you could use a generic parameter where the type implements `ISerializable`, but as you are aware that would exclude cases where serialization is declared rather than implemented.

Comment: Yes. I have possibly other ways to do that. But this isn't what I asked. Still good to know I can do that. I can see quite a few other interesting applications for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you could further restrict things so that only objects that implement ISerializable are allowed then you could use generics to get compile-time checking

```
public void Serialize<T>(T obj) where T : ISerializable
{
    // Do work
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't count as an answer to your question because not every `Serializable` class implements `ISerializable`